# How to use kmeans function on data stored using datastore function?

Tags: matlab, csv, parallel-processing, k-means

I'm trying to cluster big data using kmeans, i found a code that can do something similar here you are

```
Mu = bsxfun(@times,ones(20,30),(1:20)'); % Gaussian mixture mean
rn30 = randn(30,30);
Sigma = rn30'*rn30; % Symmetric and positive-definite covariance
Mdl = gmdistribution(Mu,Sigma);

rng(1); % For reproducibility
X = random(Mdl,10000);
%%
pool = parpool;                      % Invokes workers

stream = RandStream('mlfg6331_64');  % Random number stream
options = statset('UseParallel',1,'UseSubstreams',1,...
'Streams',stream);

%%

tic;
[idx,C,sumd,D] = kmeans(X,20,'Options',options,'MaxIter',10000,...
'Display','final','Replicates',10);
toc % Terminate stopwatch timer
```

But as you can see, X is double.

My problem is that i have a file named HIS.csv and i used the datastore function to store it as follows

```
ds = datastore('HIS_all.csv', 'DatastoreType', 'tabulartext','TreatAsMissing', 'NA');
```

when i tried

```
 [idx,C,sumd,D] = kmeans(ds,20,'Options',options,'MaxIter',10000, 'Display','final','Replicates',10);
```

i get the following error

```
 Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type         'matlab.io.datastore.TabularTextDatastore'.

 Error in kmeans (line 158)
 wasnan = any(isnan(X),2);
```

I'm using matlab 2015a

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it give you an `out of memory error` if you try `T = readall(ds);`

Comment: no, it doesn't give me this error